# Tracking upload progress with OCI transfer package

Tags: go, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I was trying to set up a file uploader to OCI Object Storage, it is working fine so far, but I am not able to tell the current progress of a upload.

My function looks like this:

```golang
uploadObjectStorage := func(filePath, fileName string) {
        file, err := os.Open(filePath)

        if err != nil {
            panic("Could not open file for read")
        }

        ociUploadRequest := transfer.UploadRequest{
            NamespaceName: oci_namespace,
            BucketName:    oci_bucketname,
            ObjectName:    common.String(fileName),
            RequestMetadata: common.RequestMetadata{
                RetryPolicy: &oci_retry,
            },
        }

        req := transfer.UploadStreamRequest{
            UploadRequest: ociUploadRequest,
            StreamReader:  file,
        }

        _, err = transfer.NewUploadManager().UploadStream(context.Background(), req)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```

There is a type called transfer.UploadCallBack "that gets invoked after a Part is successuly uploaded", however I didn't manage to make it work.

- Go version go1.21.1
- windows/amd64
- oci-go-sdk version v65.49.1

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it with `transfer.UploadCallBack`, but after some searching I found an example of [how to track a download progress](https://github.com/joncrlsn/go-examples/blob/master/http-download-with-progress.go) and it works for uploads too!

Here is how I did it:

First create a struct to keep track of the current progress and the total file size, and a function to print the current percentage

```golang
type Progress struct {
    // current progress
    Current int64
    // total file size
    Total int64
}
// Print progress
func (wc *Progress) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n := len(p)
    wc.Current += int64(n)
    fmt.Printf("Uploading... %.2f%%", float64(wc.Current)/float64(wc.Total)*100)
    return n, nil
}
```

After opening a file, pass the total file size to the struct

```golang
// file is a *os.File from os.Open() return
stats, err := (file.Stat())
// error handling
progressRead := &Progress{
    Total: stats.Size(),
}
```

Then use `io.TeeReader` on `StreamReader` field of `transfer.UploadStreamRequest`

```golang
req := transfer.UploadStreamRequest{
        UploadRequest: ociUploadRequest,
        StreamReader:  io.TeeReader(file, progressRead),
    }
```